# SQL Server : how to return 1 row Boolean/string from in SELECT from multiple rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, boolean

I am trying to return condensed information from objects with many relationships / lines tied to them. I understand what is happening but I don't know how to prevent this in SQL. I am specifying for the query to return a condition based on every line.

Is there an aggregate function to do this? Something like an ANY function to only return 1 value? I know this is possible with things like SUM and AVG. I tried IF EXISTS with no success. Maybe I was using it incorrectly.

If this is isn't possible, then I have to write some code for this. Not difficult, but it would more difficult for future people to maintain the reports/analytics.

Here is an example data set if it helps. It's similar but still quite different than from the info

Data set:

[image]

Current results:

[image]

Desired results:

[image]

Here is my example query:

```
SELECT
    orderId,
    (CASE WHEN shippingMethod = 'Expedited' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'NO' END) AS isExpedited,
    (CASE WHEN itemsUnder10 < 10 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'NO' END) AS itemsUnder10
FROM 
    [Db].[dbo].[exampleTable]
GROUP BY
    orderId
```

How can I get to my desired results?

Let me know if I can provide better information.

EDIT: Forgot to add GROUP BY. Sorry. Adding it in

Comment: A group by should be enough i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want aggregation:

```
SELECT orderId,
       MAX(CASE WHEN shippingMethod = 'Expedited' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'NO' END) AS isExpedited
       MAX(CASE WHEN itemsUnder10 < 10 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'NO' END) AS itemsUnder10
FROM [Db].[dbo].[exampleTable]
GROUP BY orderID;
```

Comment: I feel like like an idiot. I just automatically assumed to only use MAX for numerical values/datetime You're the best!.

Comment: Hello, i am currently testing it out. There are cases when it is not picking up things I'm specifying. Using MIN seems to fix this. What is going on?

Comment: @Noctsol . . . With "YES" and "NO", `MIN()` is equivalent to `AND` (all must be "YES" to get "YES").  `MAX()` is equivalent to `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to group your result

```
SELECT
orderId,
(CASE WHEN shippingMethod = 'Expedited' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'NO' END) AS isExpedited
(CASE WHEN itemsUnder10 < 10 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'NO' END) AS itemsUnder10
FROM 
[Db].[dbo].[exampleTable]
GROUP BY orderId
,shippingMethod
, itemsUnder10
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52940001/sql-server-how-to-return-1-row-boolean-string-from-in-select-from-multiple-row